# can we have select2 behavior in lightning components

Tags: lightning, lightningselect, lightning-components

[image]

Is it possible to provide search mechanism in picklists with lightning component as shown in image?

Please let me know if anyone has idea.

Comment: You can see this post at github https://github.com/chaturvedijai/SF-Lightning-Lookup

Answer (score 0):

searchable pick list are not part of standard salesforce components. You can build your custom component for that or you can use strike library.
http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikePicklist

[image]

Comment: Thanks Manjot. Is there any option with out using third party code?